# Customize Ejb Timer Schedule without Rebuilding War

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss-eap-7

I am using a ejb timer in my code as follows:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class Notifier {

    @Inject
    Logger LOG;

    @Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/mail/Default")
    private Session mailSession;

    @Schedule(minute = "0", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void notify()  {

    }
}
```

I would like to be able to reconfigure the scheduler without having to rebuild and upload the resulting war to the server each time I decide that I need to tweak the schedule.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a system property and the `ScheduleExpression`. Or you could use a [programmatic EJB Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#giqlt).

Another option would be to use a `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` and use a `Trigger` to control the next run time. Again you could use a system property or just a configuration file that lives outside the application.